# A graphical message to decode

Tags: visual

I created this puzzle.
If Surgery is coded as:

[image: Surgery]

Fibonacci as :

[image: Fibonacci]

Paperfolding as:

[image: Paperfolding]

Rudin-Shapiro as:

[image: Rudin-Shapiro]

Twin Towers as:

[image: Twin Towers]

And Blacksmith is coded as:

[image: Blacksmith]

How will Parachute be coded?

Hint 1:

> The one you use to answer the questions in this site.

Hint 2:

> An Unfamiliar one.

Hint 3:

> The images are subjected to scale. Writing the amplitudes down may help.

Hint 4:

> 

Lay

Hint 5:

> Don't edit this post to correct the mistakes that seem obvious. (Yes, this is also a hint.)

Keep a keen mind on the hints.

Comment: possibly a rot13-encoded comment (not sure about its usefulness though): vf vg vagraqrq gung nyy rapbqvatf fgneg jvgu gur fnzr cnggrea? Va rvgure pnfr, V fhfcrpg gung n yvar gung funecyl tbrf qbja ercerfragf n fcnpr, naq gung rnpu arkg vzntr vf gur rapbqvat bs gur pheerag zrffntr naq nyy cerivbhf barf, frcnengrq ol fcnprf.

Comment: It looks like each encoded word rot13(pbagnvaf nyy gur cerivbhf barf)...

Comment: @johnbrookfields I think the link to your other puzzle is unnecessary: if anyone is interested they can use the search engine of PSE. Besides, you should link a page with the search results (like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a38010%20is%3aquestion)) that updates automatically every time you post a new question so that you don't have to manually update the google docs --and we won't have to open the google doc.

Comment: What's this? The entire puzzle suddenly changed? That's not how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: I am really sorry for the inconvenience. I forgot a number in all of them. Took 1 character less than the total. I added scales for more clarity. @Bass

Comment: I think the letter P was not encoded in the original, but I don't think I'm going to redo my answer. Nowadays, when I post a puzzle, I usually type it in, sleep on it, and reread it in the morning: that way I can catch most (not all) of the mistakes I made before they are published. There's never any hurry to post a question, the site isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @melfnt Thanks for that. I didn't know that. I will refrain from doing it again. Thanks again for saying that.

Comment: rot13(Guvf pbhyq or eryngrq gb gur cbfvgvbaf ba na hasnzvyvne pbzchgre xrlobneq ynlbhg (nyy gur uvagf) nf pbzzba yrggref yvxr b/y/v/q ner va gur zvqqyr naq hapbzzba yrggref yvxr z/o/p, e/j/x ner arne gur bhgfxvegf nobir naq orybj. Ohg V pna'g trg vg gb pbeeryngr gb nal. Vg vf irel pybfr gb n srj ohg gurer ner fbzr bhgyvref. Abgvat gung rira jvgu gur hcqngrf, 'r' nccrnef va gjb frcnengr l cbfvgvbaf, V jbaqre vs gurer znl rira or nqqvgvbany reebef va gur chmmyr. Bgurejvfr gurer vf fbzrguvat ryfr tbvat ba, be vg vf abg nf fvzcyr nf 1:1 znccvat gb cbfvgvba.)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer

Two realizations:

> first, as jafe has observed similarly, each graph represents a continuation of the previous one, as shown below:

> [image]

Second, as inspired by monicareinstate's comment: there actually *is* an inherent pattern in each progression. It turns out

> Each individual letter has a unique height. If we match each twist in the graph to each letter (ignoring spaces and hyphens), we have this graph (here I used a horizontally stretched version of "Fibonacci"):

> [image: table of progression]

This is apparent from

> the same heights of the two consecutive "c"s in Fibbonaci, two capital "T"s in Twin Towers, etc. Note that uppercase letters have a different height than that of lowercase letters.

Final thoughts

> It seems intentional that "e" and "r" in "Twin Towers" overlap (their heights are very similar) because otherwise each other letter matches previously established heights perfectly. Hint 1 and 2 are still a mystery and I doubt "visual" is the only tag applicable to this question; it does not seem there is convenient way to produce the code even though it is clear *what it should look like* (every letter in "parachute" has a precedent already given). But I am confident somebody will figure it out :).

Comment: Nice thought @A.O. But hyphens and spaces are **NOT NEGLECTED**. But I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: And, try to find how the hints relate to the question @A.O. And there is a relation to the height. That's why this image **is to scale**.